# how to refine php if statement using empty

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, advanced-custom-fields

I would like to understand how i could refine this piece of code:

```php
<?php if( get_sub_field('which_call_to_action') == 'primary_cta' ):
$PopOrPage = get_field('page_or_pop_up', 'option');
$StandardOrAdvanced = get_field('secondary_more_options_cta', 'option');
$AddUrl = get_field('cta_page_url', 'option');
$TextOnButton = the_field('main_cta_text', 'option');?>
<?php echo '<div class="'. $StandardOrAdvanced .'"><a class="'. $PopOrPage .'" href="'. $AddUrl .'">' ;?>
    <?php echo $TextOnButton ;?>
    <?php echo '</a></div>';?>
<?php elseif ( get_sub_field('which_call_to_action') == 'secondary_cta' ):
$StandardOrAdvanced = get_field('secondary_more_options_cta', 'option');
$TextOnButton = get_field('secondary_cta_group_secondary_text', 'option');
$AddUrl = get_field('secondary_cta_group_secondary_url', 'option');?>
<?php echo '<div class="'. $StandardOrAdvanced .'"><a class="'. $PopOrPage .'" href="'. $AddUrl .'">' ;?>
    <?php echo $TextOnButton ;?>
    <?php echo '</a></div>';?>
<?php elseif ( get_sub_field('which_call_to_action') == 'tertiary_cta' ):
$StandardOrAdvanced = get_field('secondary_more_options_cta', 'option');
$TextOnButton = get_field('tertiary_cta_group_tertiary_text', 'option');
$AddUrl = get_field('tertiary_cta_group_tertiary_url', 'option');?>
<?php echo '<div class="'. $StandardOrAdvanced .'"><a class="'. $PopOrPage .'" href="'. $AddUrl .'">' ;?>
    <?php echo $TextOnButton ;?>
    <?php echo '</a></div>';?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

is there a way to not have to repeat the part below so many times?

```php
<?php echo '<div class="'. $StandardOrAdvanced .'"><a class="'. $PopOrPage .'" href="'. $AddUrl .'">' ;?>
    <?php echo $TextOnButton ;?>
    <?php echo '</a></div>';?>
```

I tried this:

```php
<?php if( get_sub_field('which_call_to_action') == 'primary_cta' ){
$PopOrPage = get_field('page_or_pop_up', 'option');
$StandardOrAdvanced = get_field('secondary_more_options_cta', 'option');
$AddUrl = get_field('cta_page_url', 'option');
$TextOnButton = the_field('main_cta_text', 'option');}

elseif ( get_sub_field('which_call_to_action') == 'secondary_cta' ){
$StandardOrAdvanced = get_field('secondary_more_options_cta', 'option');
$TextOnButton = get_field('secondary_cta_group_secondary_text', 'option');
$AddUrl = get_field('secondary_cta_group_secondary_url', 'option');}

elseif ( get_sub_field('which_call_to_action') == 'tertiary_cta' ){
$StandardOrAdvanced = get_field('secondary_more_options_cta', 'option');
$TextOnButton = get_field('tertiary_cta_group_tertiary_text', 'option');
$AddUrl = get_field('tertiary_cta_group_tertiary_url', 'option');}

echo '<div class="'. $StandardOrAdvanced .'"><a class="'. $PopOrPage .'" href="'. $AddUrl .'">' ;
    echo $TextOnButton ;
    echo '</a></div>';
endif; ?>
```

and i was expecting it run through each `if statement` and load the necessary variables and output the html accordingly. alas the code failed

Comment: You can define your variables with defaults before your if/else blocks, then only echo after the endif. Also `$StandardOrAdvanced = get_field('secondary_more_options_cta', 'option');` is on all 3 blocks, so you can put that before or after your if/else as well

Answer (score 0):

Give your variables some default values, then you only need to overwrite them if necessary in your if/else blocks. This will allow you to move the echoes to the end of the code block. `$StandardOrAdvanced` is the same in all 3 blocks, so move that before or after your if/else.

```php
$PopOrPage = ''; // empty string or add your default value
$AddUrl = '';// empty string or add your default value
$StandardOrAdvanced = get_field('secondary_more_options_cta', 'option');

if(get_sub_field('which_call_to_action') == 'primary_cta'):
    $PopOrPage = get_field('page_or_pop_up', 'option');
    $AddUrl = get_field('cta_page_url', 'option');
    $TextOnButton = the_field('main_cta_text', 'option');
elseif(get_sub_field('which_call_to_action') == 'secondary_cta'):
    $TextOnButton = get_field('secondary_cta_group_secondary_text', 'option');
    $AddUrl = get_field('secondary_cta_group_secondary_url', 'option');
elseif(get_sub_field('which_call_to_action') == 'tertiary_cta'):
    $TextOnButton = get_field('tertiary_cta_group_tertiary_text', 'option');
    $AddUrl = get_field('tertiary_cta_group_tertiary_url', 'option');
endif;

echo '<div class="' . $StandardOrAdvanced . '"><a class="' . $PopOrPage . '" href="' . $AddUrl . '">';
echo $TextOnButton;
echo '</a></div>';
```